# I dont know why my image url doesn't work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I got this path for the image:

[image: Image path]

on my code, I got this :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="../galery/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
<div>
```

I still don't get the image, I don't know what is the problem

Comment: check in the browser console in the path is correct, probably not

Answer (score 0):

The file on your local drive is not a file on your web server. It is not enough to just put an image into the folder you need to create an endpoint on your server that will return an image by a specific GET request from the browser.

try to add to your APP.js

```
app.use("/galery", express.static(__dirname + "/galery"));
```

and change img url to following

`<img src="/galery/logo.png" alt="logo">`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which framework/language you are using. Anyway, Generally almost all language might have some common file to set/get global variables. Incase if your framework have such things. Try to set image path to gallary and use it in img tag's src attribute.